# ng-repeat inside document with specific ID

Tags: angularjs, node.js, pug, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've a document with array inside eg.:

```
$scope.items = [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Apple"
        "types": [{ 
                  "color": "red"
                  "size": "xxl
                 },
                 {
                  "color: "green"
                  "size": "S"                                  
                 }]
      },
      { 
        ...
      }]
```

And i'd like to display all records from `Array "types"` only for items ID = 1.

I tried this (doesn't work):

```
table(style="width:100%")
     tr(ng-repeat="type in items.types" ng-if="items.id==1")
          td
              p {{ type.color}}
          td
              p {{ type.size}}
```

Comment: It's `items[0].id` or else you can also do as `type.id`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be easily implement by having two `ng-repeat` with filter, which will filter out the items which has `id` 1, and do `ng-repeat` on that `types` collection.

```
table(style="width:100%")
   tbody(ng-repeat="item in items | filter: {id: 1 }: true")
     tr(ng-repeat="type in items.types")
          td
              p {{ type.color}}
          td
              p {{ type.size}}
```

Comment: Yep, that's it. Thank you so much

Comment: @DiPix glad to help you. Thanks :-)